# How can I redirect a URL based on a response?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, redirect

For redirecting a request, I can write a servlet, make the servlet-mapping matches the URL, and use response.sendRedirect() in the servlet.

But what if the redirect URL is contained in the original URL's response? For example, the response contains an XML file which has a new URL.

In this way, it seems that servlet cannot be used, because the resource that the original URL points to is still needed. We cannot assign both a servlet and another resource(the XML file) to the same URL.

In short, I have a link: xxx/atom/aFileName.xxx , its response is an XML file.
Can I invoke a servlet with this link, but at the same time still get the response?

Any ideas how can I handle it?

Comment: HTTP redirect has nothing to to with the response body. It is done by HTTP headers.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is, I want to get the response in the servlet, but the response comes from a URL that now maps to this servlet ..... So I cannot get the response. I don't know if I can use other methods other than servlet to do the redirect

Comment: You want to have URL that at the same time return a XML resource and redirects to another URL which is contained in the XML? I'm afraid that it can't work like this for the clients. Why would you want such behaviour?

Comment: @lukelazarovic Yes! We have migrated an old system to a new system, and in the old system there are document links pointing to the target document. In the new system these document links do not work any more, they just contain the old target document URL information in an XML file. So I want to make these links more useful other than just returning me an XML file....

Comment: Why don't you simply redirects the old link to the new XML link?

Comment: @lukelazarovic Because the XML links are contained in the response. Only after a GET request can I get them. I need something to parse the response and generate the link, that's why I thought of servlet at first

Comment: Sure - you can parse a XML, obtain a new URL and redirect to it in the servlet.

Comment: @lukelazarovic That's right and also my first thought. The problem is, the XML response comes from this link: /atom/aFileName.xxx, but I have to map this URL to the servlet.

Comment: You can map any URL to your servlet.

Comment: @lukelazarovic Right...but then in the servlet when I want to get the XML response using:URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(), it actually invokes the servlet again...Not the XML response. It's like a loop, the original resource cannot be retrieved.

Comment: Then you should discard this question and write a new one for this specific problem including the code, the servlet-mapping etc.

Comment: Lookup URL Rewriting filters. You can have a filter to parse the URL `/atom/aFileName.xxx` and use the `aFileName.xxx` as a parameter. For example, you could use [tuckey-urlrewrite-filter] http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tuckey-urlrewrite-filter/info